# Index number of a just pasted Graphic

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to paste something into PPT (onto a Slide that already has objects) and then change it's size. In the following Code in line 1 I paste a range onto a previously selected slide. After that I want to set the variable shp as the shape and then change it with .top .width etc. My Problem is that the (2) in the last line needs to be the index number of the shape I just pasted. How do I do that?

```
slde.Shapes.PasteSpecial 2


Set shp = slde.Shapes(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Shapes.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.count) property like so:

```vb
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
    
sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault
Set shp = sld.Shapes(sld.Shapes.Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with objects. This way you will not have to worry about finding the right object. Here is an example

```
Dim shp As Object

Set shp = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(2)

Debug.Print shp.Name

With shp
    '~~> Do what you want here
End With
```

**TIP:**

Try and not work with direct constant values...

If you are using early binding, then change

```
Set shp = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(2)
```

to

```
Set shp = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
```

For late binding, declare this at the top

```
Const ppPasteEnhancedMetafile As Integer = 2
```

and then use

```
Set shp = sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
```

This way, even if you read the code, say, after say 6 months, you will know what that code is doing. (Just my two cents)